# Discrepancies between "ps -f" and "ps"

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, ps

We are running Red hat Enterprise 7.7 (Maipo) and for a specific oracle process I'm getting two different values under "CMD" column. See below examples:

```
ps -p [process_id]
109401 ?        00:09:57 ora_pmon_test
```

And:

```
ps -f -p [process_id] 
oracle   109401      1  0  2019 ?        00:09:57 ora_pmon_test01
```

I have put sample names, but basically "CMD" for the first output is truncated. What is the difference of these two ways of running the `ps` command?

What do these two outputs represent?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you're seeing the `comm` column, which is stored as a separate field in the process (/proc/PID/comm) and is limited to 16 bytes.

In the second case you're seeing the `command` aka `cmd` aka `args` column, which is taken directly from the process' command line (/proc/PID/cmdline) and has no such limit.